# C++ combination function always resulting 0

Tags: c++, recursion, factorial

can anybody tell me why my Combination function is always resulting 0 ?
I also tried to make it calculate the combination without the use of the permutation function but the factorial and still the result is 0;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int& n)
{
  if (n <= 1)
  {
     return 1;
  }
  else 
  {
    n = n-1;
    return (n+1) * factorial(n);
  }
}
int permutation(int& a, int& b)
{
  int x = a-b;
  return factorial(a) / factorial(x);
}
int Combination(int& a, int& b)
{
   return permutation(a,b) / factorial(b);
}

int main()
{
   int f, s;
   cin >> f >> s;

   cout << permutation(f,s) << endl;
   cout << Combination(f,s);


  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should show your input values - or better, write a [mcve] that doesn't need any input.

Comment: You use call by reference in `factorial(int& n)` and decrease the value of `n` on each function call.
To avoid this in the future, use `const` in the future to get a compiler warning when manipulating values that should stay constant.

Answer (score 9):

Your immediate problem is that that you pass a modifiable *reference* to your function.  This means that you have Undefined Behaviour here:

```
return (n+1) * factorial(n);
//      ^^^             ^^^
```

because `factorial(n)` modifies `n`, and is indeterminately sequenced with `(n+1)`.  A similar problem exists in `Combination()`, where `b` is modified twice in the same expression:

```
return permutation(a,b) / factorial(b);
//                  ^^^            ^^^
```

You will get correct results if you pass `n`, `a` and `b` *by value*, like this:

```
int factorial(int n)
```

Now, `factorial()` gets its own *copy* of n, and doesn't affect the `n+1` you're multiplying it with.

---

While we're here, I should point out some other flaws in the code.

- Avoid `using namespace std;` - it has traps for the unwary (and even for the wary!).
- You can write `factorial()` without modifying `n` once you pass by value (rather than by reference):

  ```
  int factorial(const int n)
  {
      if (n <= 1) {
          return 1;
      } else {
          return n * factorial(n-1);
      }
  }
  ```
- Consider using iterative code to compute factorial.
- We should probably be using `unsigned int`, since the operations are meaningless for negative numbers.  You might consider `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` for greater range.
- Computing one factorial and dividing by another is not only inefficient, it also risks unnecessary overflow (when `a` is as low as 13, with 32-bit `int`).  Instead, we can multiply just down to the other number:

  ```
  unsigned int permutation(const unsigned int a, const unsigned int b)
  {
      if (a < b) return 0;

      unsigned int permutations = 1;
      for (unsigned int i = a;  i > a-b;  --i) {
          permutations *= i;
      }

      return permutations;
  }
  ```

  This works with much higher `a`, when `b` is small.
- We didn't need the `<cmath>` header for anything.

---

Suggested fixed code:

```
unsigned int factorial(const unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int result = 1;

    for (unsigned int i = 2;  i <= n;  ++i) {
        result *= i;
    }

    return result;
}

unsigned int permutation(const unsigned int a, const unsigned int b)
{
    if (a < b) return 0;

    unsigned int result = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = a;  i > a-b;  --i) {
        result *= i;
    }

    return result;
}

unsigned int combination(const unsigned int a, const unsigned int b)
{
    // C(a, b) == C(a, a - b), but it's faster to compute with small b
    if (b > a - b) {
        return combination(a, a - b);
    }

    return permutation(a,b) / factorial(b);
}
```

Comment: In addition, `int` is likely to be faster than `int&` (smaller and no indirection)

Comment: I was also going to comment on the implementation. The biggest factorial that a 32bit int can represent is 12 (see here http://2000clicks.com/MathHelp/BasicFactorialTable.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Paul - I was to lazy to work it out, but I've incorporated that fact into my answer.

Answer (score -7):

You dont calculate with the pointer value you calculate withe the pointer address.